# bottom width not adjusted

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to configure this bottom part of my CSS layout, but can't seem to figure out how to do it.

```
body {
    background: #f9f9f9;
    font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
    color: #777;
    font-size:13px;
    line-height:25px;
}


#footer {
    background: #1b1b1b url("../images2/footer.jpg") repeat top;
    padding:50px 0;
    width:100%;
    color: #867f72;
}
```

code:

```
<!-- START #footer -->
    <div id="footer">
        vxsvsd
    </div>
    <!-- END #footer -->
```

live preview: http://www.krissales.me/user/tyler/whmcs/index.php

scroll down, do you guys happen to know why it's not sitting against the bottom of the screen? instead, it shows a huge gap. Am I not aligning something right?

thanks !

Comment: I don't see any gap, plus you don't have any positioning in your CSS so it will just appear below your main content

Comment: what bottom gap exactly?

Comment: the gap right here: http://uploadir.com/u/96kpw0bc u see that gap at the bottom? is it because there's not enough content in the main div to push that footer down below?

Comment: Don't see a gap? What browser?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have no gap at all add this to your footer style:

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0px;
```

Be warned though: this will show the footer *always* on the bottom, which means that it can, and most probably will overlap your main content. I'd suggest adding a `min-height` for your main content to prevent this. Or just give up and leave it as it is.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a fixed height for the footer, you can use the trick from: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page

In short:
Set 'positioning: absolute' and 'bottom: 0' for the footer, and then set the bottom padding for the main element to the height of the footer. There also needs to be a wrapper element with 'min-height: 100%' and 'positioning: relative'.